# Pipes. components injection to component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In Angular2 RC.4 I can inject components and pipes to each component.

```
@Component({
  pipes: [ ToShortTime, ToTimeZone],
  directives: [Restaurant, Spinner]
})
```

How can I do this in released version of Angular2. ( For example inject some pipe only in one component, not using "declarations" in NgModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible!

You could create a Module including just that component..

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing (I migrated from rc4 to final release); so I created my own spinner component (spinner.component).

1) in app.module :

I imported SpinnerComponent in declarations and SpinnerService in providers.

2) in app.component.html:

I added `<spinner-component></spinner-component>` before or after `router-outlet`

3) in login.component :

I imported SpinnerService (and set declared it in constructor)

and finaly I use this service each http request/response

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is possible from template side or not. But am sure it is possible through JavaScript (from Component's class).

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EDWfnnhe4NYsewpOoFhP?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

class LengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, displayMessage: boolean): string {
    return displayMessage ? `${value} ${value.length}` : `${value.length}`
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><p>{{title}}</p><button (click)="doPipe()">Call Pipe</button>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  title: String = 'Title';
  doPipe() {
    let f = new LengthPipe();
    this.title = f.transform(this.title,true)
  }
}
```